# Prestashop 1.4 Issue on cart update (currency conversion)

Tags: php, prestashop, currency, currency-exchange-rates

I have a weird issue when I do the **$cart->update();** after changing the currency

e.g. in pounds the total amount from the cart is **£896.32**
with the current conversion rate **1.388889** (to EUR)

so, in EUR it should be 896.32 * 1.388889 = 1244.89 (rounded 2)

BUT If I'm on checkout and on payment module I do:

```
$cookie->id_currency = 1; //1 for EUR
$cart->id_currency = $cookie->id_currency;
$cart->update();
//and then...
$amount = number_format($cart->getOrderTotal(true, 3), 2, '.', '');
```

it goes completely wrong... the final **$total** variable is wrong.

DEBUG CONSOLE: 
**BEFORE $cart->update();**

```
$cart   Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Cart Object (14)
   ->id = 2899
   ->id_address_delivery = "5"
   ->id_address_invoice = "5"
   ->id_currency = "3"
   ->id_customer = "3"
   ->id_guest = "998683"
   ->id_lang = "1"
   ->id_carrier = "14"
   ->recyclable = "1"
   ->gift = "0"
   ->gift_message = ""
   ->date_add = "2015-12-09 10:08:27"
   ->secure_key = "5b5c81dbecc7b7e1d9603752071321b7"
   ->date_upd = "2015-12-09 17:17:15"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root"


$total  Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "£896.32"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root"
```

**AFTER $cart->update();**

```
$cart   Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Cart Object (14)
   ->id = 2899
   ->id_address_delivery = "5"
   ->id_address_invoice = "5"
   ->id_currency = 1
   ->id_customer = "3"
   ->id_guest = "998683"
   ->id_lang = "1"
   ->id_carrier = "14"
   ->recyclable = "1"
   ->gift = "0"
   ->gift_message = ""
   ->date_add = "2015-12-09 10:08:27"
   ->secure_key = "5b5c81dbecc7b7e1d9603752071321b7"
   ->date_upd = "2015-12-09 17:19:41"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root"

$total  Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "1 239,67 €"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root"
```

as you can see, that **1 239,67 €** is wrong and should be **1 244,89 €**, instead.

Please, Where is the error? I'm going crazy for that.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND the issue

there is the **additional_shipping_cost** field on database which is not updated when you change currency.
I don't know if in the latest PS versions the behavior is different, but that is an oversight by developers for sure.